# How to Check that all Ajax get Completed

Tags: php, ajax

I am using multiples ajax on page

```
1. $.load("abc.com/users");
2. $.load("abc.com/usersrates"); 
3. ..... 
4. .......
```

and there is one next button to go to another page which is disable now i want to enable this next button when all Ajax get completed.

Any Idea Will appreciated.

Comment: $.load is provided with a complete callback .. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Syed Qurib But here is not single $.load then how?

Comment: @JitendraYadav Use complete callback for each..

Comment: Use .ajaxComplete() Method. For details follow

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.when`, for multiple ajax call.

example:

```
 $.when( $.load("abc.com/users"), $.load("abc.com/usersrates"))
      .then( successCallback, errorCallback );
```

For more Info See This [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: its show the next button early completion of response. I want to check the condition when all load functions are completed their response. But it show the before completion of all requests.

Answer (score 0):

**edit:** The `$.when` responses in this are far better!

This is a bit hacky but will work

```
<script>
var totalLoads = 2;
var currentLoad = 0;

function checkLoads()
{
    if (currentLoad == totalLoads)
    {
        // enable button
    }
}

$.load("abc.com/users", funciton() { currentLoad++; checkLoads(); });
$.load("abc.com/usersrates", funciton() { currentLoad++; checkLoads(); })); 
</script>
```

Comment: Its work fine. Is there any short method, I mean can i achieve this by aJax global function or in short way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$.when` .

```
    $.when( $.ajax(...), $.ajax( ... ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {



      }
    }).failed(function(f1,f2){ 


  });
```

> // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data,
>   statusText, jqXHR ]
>
> // **a1** and **a2** are arguments resolved for the first and second ajax
>   successful requests, respectively.
>    // **f1** and **f2** are arguments
>   resolved for the first and second ajax failed requests, respectively.